# BizTalk application fails to install: "newer version of the application installed"

Tags: windows, windows-installer, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am having issues installing a BizTalk application using the msi-installer generated by BizTalk deployment framework.

When I run the installer, I instantly get an error telling me that there is a newer version of the application installed on the computer.

I have tried to look for the BizTalk application on the computer, but I am pretty sure that it isn't there.

Does anyone have any similar experiences? 
What might cause such error?

Comment: Are you getting the same error, when using "Deploy solution" button in visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone had copied the Product Upgrade Code in the Deployment file from another solution. I changed it to a new guid, and the application installed fine.